# Understanding names of shared library in linux

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I've read linux documentation project and I still don't understand what exactly purpose of `soname` and `real name`.

Let I've three files: `main.cpp`, `header.h` and `test.cpp`. I've written the following Makefile:

```
bin: main.o test.so
    g++ -o bin main.o -ltest  -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
main.o:main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
test.so: test.o
    g++ -shared -o libtest.so test.o
test.o: test.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -c test.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so* bin
```

I've run this make file, I've copied libtest.so into the `/usr/local/lib` and it's ok. But I don't understand what is the `soname` and `real name` in my case?

Let's rewrite this Makefile:

```
bin: main.o test.so
    g++ -o bin main.o -L. -ltest  -Wl,-rpath .
main.o:main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
test.so: test.o
    g++ -shared -Wl,soname,-litest.so.1 -o libtest.so.1.0.1 test.o
test.o: test.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -c test.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so* bin
```

But it doesn't work. The following error was caused:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: @oakad Can you read my topic? **I've read linux documentation project and I still don't understand what exactly purpose of soname and real name. **

Answer (score 0):

> But it doesn't work. The following error was caused: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest

It seems you use a wrong option.

1) -rpath is for runtime library search path. All -rpath arguments are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker ld.so See `man ld.so`.

2) -L is for `ld` when linking your program or shared library (this is from `man ld`:  All -L options apply to all -l options)

So when building you need to use -L to tell the linker `ld`where to find libraries (and remember - `ld.so` is used when you start your program, `ld` when you link it) :

```
g++ -o bin main.o -L. -ltest  -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: How can I to specify soname, real name and version of a shared library? What is the version of the library created by the `g++ -shared -o libtest.so test.o`

Comment: 1) How can I specify soname, real name and version of a shared library?  -- Example from the doc: `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmystuff.so.1 -o libmystuff.so.1.0.1 a.o b.o`. Soname - libmystuff.so.1, RealName - libmystuff.so.1.0.1, The version of its interface is 1 (since soname has 1 after so: libmystuff.so.1), the version of the library is 1.0.1. 2) In your example there is no version in the soname of libtest.so.